# x86 Forth implementation doesn't run

Tags: x86, gdb, x86-64, forth

I'm trying to run [JonesForth](http://rwmj.wordpress.com/2010/08/07/jonesforth-git-repository/) (Git repository: git://git.annexia.org/git/jonesforth.git) on a 64-bit Linux box. Compilation is as mentioned in the tutorial, is used in the Makefile, and works fine:

```
gcc -m32 -nostdlib -static -Wl,-Ttext,0  -o jonesforth jonesforth.S
```

But I can't run anything:

```
➜  jonesforth git:(master) ✗ cat pgm.f | ./jonesforth
[1]    16997 done       cat pgm.f |
       16998 killed     ./jonesforth
➜  jonesforth git:(master) ✗ ./jonesforth
[1]    17006 killed     ./jonesforth
➜  jonesforth git:(master) ✗ echo $?
137
```

Exit code 137 looks like SIGKILL, but other than that, I have no idea what's going on. I tried to see if anything goes wrong in execution, but unfortunately I can't even use [GDB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Debugger) on that program (I'm first compiling it with `-g`):

```
➜  jonesforth git:(master) ✗ gdb jonesforth
...
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/omer/opt/jonesforth/jonesforth
During startup program terminated with signal SIGKILL, Killed.
```

What's going wrong?

Comment: I haven't read his tutorial, but do you really want `-Wl,-Ttext,0`? That doesn't seem like something you'd use when building a Linux application. Was the tutorial aimed at building a Forth interpreter for bare metal systems where you boot straight into the interpreter?

Comment: @Michael you're right. I didn't add that parameter myself, it's set in the Makefile. If you post your comment as answer I'll accept it because it solved my problem.

Comment: There is a x86_64 bit version at http://subvert-the-dominant-paradigm.net/repos/hgwebdir.cgi/jonesforth64 (mercurial repository). It works, but the comments are x86_32 still. Also, I have some doubts on the exception handling (catch, throw) as it looks at first sight as it is still assuming 4-byte cells. And yes, you need to lose the "-Wl,-Ttext,0" and perhaps add "-Wl,--build-id=none"